# resizing partition using multipathd

Tags: linux, multipath

redhat 6.3 with a multipath xfs partition.

i have already increased the LUN and need to reflect the increase in the filesystem. using xfs_growfs will not work yet unless i increased the partition size. since it's a multipath, i found there is this command to do that named "multipathd", the command to be used is

*multipathd resize map multipath_device*

for those who have already done it, is this command destructive or not? i'd like to run it on an online filesystem (backup is done).

Comment: found out that, yes it is multipath, but the implementors didn't use LVM so that only way i can resize is to do a destructive one. i found out when using "vgdisplay" produces no volume groups when it should had they use lvm. bummer.l

Comment: You can do all changes online. No need to reboot or unmount.

Answer (score 0):

I run this hot all the time and it is not destructive.  However I'm using ext4 partitions on LVM2 rather than xfs and using resize2fs but that should make no difference.

https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/DM_Multipath/online_device_resize.html is Red Hat's doc.

Comment: thanks. much helpful. though in my case it's not applicable now i found out.

Answer (score 0):

Running `for scsi_device in /sys/class/scsi_device/*; do echo 1 > $scsi_device/device/rescan; done` then `multipathd reconfigure` should make it see the extra space then you can continue with the rest of the commands to resize the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a script that is preparing all commands for resize.
It will not change anything so it is safe to test it on any server.
If you find any bugs I am happy to fix them.

https://github.com/mircea-vutcovici/scripts/blob/master/vol_resize.sh